# Need to filter what shows on field

Tags: jquery

I have a field called ResponseLog_Date where I like to set a default date. As such, I am doing the following:

```
  $('#ResponseLog_Date').datepicker({
     format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

I also have other date fields that just need the date picker:

```
   // Date picker
   $('input[name$="Date"]').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
   });
```

What is happening is that #ResponseLog_Date appears with 2 pickers as it ends with "Date".

I tried the following but got the same result:

```
  // Date picker
  $('input[name$="Date"]' && 'input[name!="#ResponseLog_Date"]').datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
  });
```

Comment: A logical AND in selectors is performed by placing both selectors together, without a space.  A logical OR in selectors is done by using commas.  `'input[name$="Date"]' && 'input[name!="#ResponseLog_Date"]'` is not valid

Answer (score 1):

`'input[name$="Date"]' && 'input[name!="#ResponseLog_Date"]'` evaluates to just `'input[name!="#ResponseLog_Date"]'`, you can use `:not` to exclude certain elements (in this case, the element having the id `ResponseLog_Date`):

```
$('input[name$="Date"]:not(#ResponseLog_Date)').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
```